# DataTable ReadXml throws exception on decimal conversion

Tags: c#, xml, decimal

I have DataTable which contains decimal field. Also, I have xml file with data.
In this file, decimals using comma separator instead of dot.
When I try to run this code:

```
var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlText));
dataTable.ReadXml(xmlTextReader);
```

It throws exception "Input string was not in a correct format".
How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add your xml text. Also, try to parse simple xml files first and continue with more critical ones to find the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

XML containing decimal values with comma is not a valid XML according to the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal). 
The specification states:

> finite-length sequence of decimal digits (#x30-#x39) **separated by a
>   period** as a decimal indicator